# How to delete elements of array in angularJs

Tags: arrays, angularjs

In view I defined a button like -> 
`<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="reset(path)">Reset</button>`

And I want this function to reset an array which has been defined inside the controller.

Controller Code

```js
app.controller('mainCtrl',function(NgMap,$scope){
  var vm = this;
     $scope.path = [];
     vm.addMarkerAndPath = function(event) {
       $scope.path.push([event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()]);
       console.log($scope.path);
     };
     
     $scope.reset = function(){
  
      $scope.path.length=0;
            $scope.path =[]; // also tried this but didn't work
     }
});
```

Html Code

```js
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="srmmobileHoardingCtrl as vm">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  Save Path for hoarding Advertisement
 </div>
<ng-map zoom="7" center="41.879535, -87.624333" on-click="vm.addMarkerAndPath()">
    <shape name="polyline" id="foo"
      path="{{path}}"
      stroke-color="#FF0000"
      stroke-opacity="1.0"
      stroke-weight="3">
    </shape>
  </ng-map>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <Button class="btn btn-default">Save</Button>
   <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add the html code, or better try to create a plunkr or fiddler.

Comment: It looks like you are using both `$scope` and the `controllerAs` syntax to bind your data. Bad idea.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Actually I'm new to angularJs so could you suggest me some better way

Comment: Additionally to what @DeblatonJeanPhilippe mentioned, you define the `controller('mainCtrl'` but in html you use `ng-controller="srmmobileHoardingCtrl as vm"` which points co a different controller.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe then Can you please suggest me how to call addMArkerAndPAth function without vm.

I tried to use $scope but it didn't work.

Comment: @Anonymous have a look at this : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers

Comment: Here is simple fiddle for pushing and clearnig array: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19959/ in your js mark refactor your vm.addMarkerAndPath to $scope.addMarkerAndPath and in html call function addMarkerAndPath() like this

Comment: @dev_in_progress I appreciate your help but it didn't work in my case 
As I have mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: the your following is correct for emptying an array, don't pass patharray in reset() function and check this link also...http://jsfiddle.net/4MttG/
if not working can you provide code here?so that i can test here

Comment: @roshini I created plunker please have look at it

http://plnkr.co/edit/ul95zk5e22hpJEoAHQ9h?p=preview

Comment: @roshini,
DianaR,
dev_in_progress,
DeblatonJean-Philippe

Thanks for your kind responses, Finally I resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the slice for remove elements.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
var fruits = fruits.slice(1, 3);
```

When you use **fruits = []** or **fruits = new Array()** lose the internal reference used by the angular.

Comment: If you need to empty whole array and prevent js loosing actual link to an Object you should use Object.assign(fruits, [])

Comment: Cool, did not know what can be done well . I generally use the array.slice (0, array.length )

Comment: It's black magic of ECMAScript 6. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @EmirMarques I knew this but I was making mistake while array initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For your responses!!

And I don't know why some one has down voted my question. :/

I was making a very silly mistake. In starting I was not initializing my path array properly. i.e my path array contains objects and each object contains [lat,lng].

$scope.path = [[,]]; //I initialized this way and now everything is working pretty well.

Controller Code

```js
'use strict';

app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,NgMap){
    $scope.path = [[,]];
    
    $scope.addMarkerAndPath = function(event) {
      $scope.path.push([event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()]);
      console.log($scope.path);
    };
    
    $scope.reset = function(){
     console.log("reset function has been called");
     console.log($scope.path);
     console.log($scope.path.length);
     $scope.path.slice(0,$scope.path.length);
     $scope.path = [[,]];;
     console.log("path array ");
     console.log($scope.path);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  Save Path for hoarding Advertisement
 </div>
<ng-map zoom="7" center="41.879535, -87.624333" on-click="addMarkerAndPath()">
    <shape name="polyline" id="foo"
      path="{{path}}"
      stroke-color="#FF0000"
      stroke-opacity="1.0"
      stroke-weight="3">
    </shape>
  </ng-map>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <Button class="btn btn-default">Save</Button>
   <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

P.S It also works pretty fine if I use

> var vm = this;  through out the controller